# Java RangeSlider OnChangeListener in Android

Tags: java, android

How to add onchangelistener on rangeslider in android Java? This is the closest I have gotten.

```
import com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider;
...
   RangeSlider intensitySlider;
...
    intensitySlider=(RangeSlider) findViewById(R.id.intensity_range);
...
       intensitySlider.addOnChangeListener(new RangeSlider.OnChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
                List<Float> b = intensitySlider.getValues();

            }
        });
```

Error Messages:
RangeSlider.OnChangeListener: Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnChangeListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onValueChange(S, float, boolean)' in 'BaseOnChangeListener'

@Override: Method does not override method from its superclass

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
intensitySlider.addOnChangeListener(new RangeSlider.OnChangeListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(@NonNull RangeSlider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
            List<Float> b = intensitySlider.getValues();

        }
    });
```